# append dict to json python flask

Tags: python, json, flask, jsonlint

As im new to coding and making my own small projects i finally encountered a problem that has bugged me for the last couple of days.

So basically what i want to do is to append my dict to a list and then dump it to a json file.

```
    username = request.form["username"]
    password = request.form["password"]
    checkbox2 = request.form["checkbox2"]
    userDict = {

             "username" : username,
             "password" : password,
             "checkbox2" : checkbox2,
         }
print(userDict)
if os.path.exist("data.json"):
    with open("data.json", "r") as f:
        all_data = json.load(f)
else:
    all_data = []
all_data.append(userDict)
with open("data.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(all_data, f)
```

This is the code i'm running with at the moment.
The Traceback i get is when sending my forms.

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site- 
packages\flask\app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "C:\Users\Marco\Desktop\test\server.py", line 28, in sendinfo
all_data = json.load(f)

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 299, in load
parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

File "C:\Users\Marco\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36- 
32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

My expected json output if data.json is empty is following

```
  {
  "all_data": [{
      "username": "test",
      "password": "test2",
      "checkbox2": "on"

  }]
}
```

If the file do have "all_data": in the file already then my expected output should be

```
    {
  "all_data": [{
          "username": "test",
          "password": "test2",
          "checkbox2": "on"
      },
      {
          "username": "test3",
          "password": "test4",
          "checkbox2": "on"
      }
  ]
}
```

This issue have been bugging me for 3 days, and i thought this would be my last resort because i'm the type of person who would like to solve it myself.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the error happens here: all_data = json.load(f) . Can you post the content of the data.json file?

Comment: @ArjaanBuijk there is no content in data.json, its completely empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your `data.json` already exist but is empty? The JSON library will throw an error in such a case! You should fill a string like `[]` in your data.json to avoid this error.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Rishav, when the file data.json exists but is empty the error comes from the **json.load(f)** statement in:

```
    if os.path.exist("data.json"):
        with open("data.json", "r") as f:
            all_data = json.load(f)
```

You can fix this by not only checking if the file exists but also that it is not empty, like this:

```
    if os.path.exist("data.json") and os.path.getsize("data.json") > 0:
        with open("data.json", "r") as f:
            all_data = json.load(f)
```

Then your code should work as expected.